# Looking up values without loop in R

Tags: r

I need to look up a value in a data frame based on multiple criteria in another data frame. Example

```
A=
Country Year Number
USA     1994 455
Canada  1997 342
Canada  1998 987
```

must have added a column by the name of "rate" coming from

```
B=
Year   USA   Canada
1993   21    654
1994   41    321
1995   56    789
1996   85    123
1997   65    456
1998   1     999
```

So that the final data frame is

```
C=
Country Year Number  Rate
USA     1994 455     41
Canada  1997 342     456
Canada  1998 987     999
```

In other words: Look up year and country from A in B and result is C. I would like to do this without a loop. I would like a general approach, such that I would be able to look up based on more than two criteria.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's another way using `data.table` that doesn't require converting the 2nd data table to long form:

```
require(data.table) # 1.9.6+
A[B, Rate := get(Country), by=.EACHI, on="Year"]
#    Country Year Number Rate
# 1:     USA 1994    455   41
# 2:  Canada 1997    342  456
# 3:  Canada 1998    987  999
```

where `A` and `B` are data.tables, and `Country` is of *character* type.

Comment: Thank you very much - voted as answer because of the nice simplicity! I did not know, I could use data.table like this.

Answer (score 3):

We can `melt` the second dataset from 'wide' to 'long' format, `merge` with the first dataset to get the expected output.

```
library(reshape2)
res <- merge(A, melt(B, id.var='Year'), 
        by.x=c('Country', 'Year'), by.y=c('variable', 'Year'))
names(res)[4] <- 'Rate'
res
#   Country Year Number Rate
#1  Canada 1997    342   456
#2  Canada 1998    987   999
#3     USA 1994    455    41
```

---

Or we can use `gather` from `tidyr` and `right_join` to get this done.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
gather(B, Country,Rate, -Year) %>%
                       right_join(., A)
#  Year Country Rate Number
#1 1994     USA   41    455
#2 1997  Canada  456    342
#3 1998  Canada  999    987
```

---

Or as @DavidArenburg mentioned in the comments, this can be also done with `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(A)`), `melt` the second dataset and join `on` 'Year', and 'Country'.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.6+
setDT(A)[melt(setDT(B), 1L, variable = "Country", value = "Rate"), 
                on = c("Country", "Year"), 
                nomatch = 0L]

#    Country Year Number Rate
# 1:     USA 1994    455   41
# 2:  Canada 1997    342  456
# 3:  Canada 1998    987  999
```

Or a shorter version (if we are not too picky no variable names)

```
setDT(A)[melt(B, 1L), on = c(Country = "variable", Year = "Year"), nomatch = 0L]
```